# Circular Motion on Banked Curve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

When a object is performing a banked turn, $\ N\cos \theta \ =mg$, does this mean that the object is sinking into the surface? Since the normal force is now greater than $\ mg\cos \theta$?

Comment: Define $\theta$?

Comment: θ would be the angle between the banked surface and the ground level

Comment: If the surface is strong enough it will provided the needed *reactive* force and the object won't sink into the surface.

Comment: Does that mean  mgcosθ = N then ?

Comment: Yes, the Normal force is $N=mg\cos\theta$.

Comment: Wait.. Ncosθ =mg, but N=mgcosθ.. Am I just confusing myself here?

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different forces at work in a banked turn: The normal force, $N$, the force of gravity on the object, $F_g$, and kinetic friction, $f_k$. We have
$$F_g=mg,\quad f_k=\mu_kN$$
In the $y$-direction, we have
$$N_y-F_g-f_k\sin\theta=0\to N\cos\theta-mg-\mu_kN\sin\theta=0$$
We substitute and rearrange, and get
$$N=\frac{mg}{\cos\theta-\mu_k\sin\theta}$$
In the case where $\mu_k=0$, we get your equation.

Because $\cos\theta\geq1$, it is clear that $N\geq mg$. What does this mean? It actually means the opposite of your conclusion. The normal force pushes away from the surface; the force of gravity pushes towards it (I think you mixed these two up). Because the normal force "wins" this battle, there is a net force inwards - the centripetal force $F_c$, which keeps the object moving in a turning circle.

Comment: According to Wikipedia and various sources. When the object is traveling on a banked curve "Because there is no motion in the vertical direction, the sum of all vertical forces acting on the system must be zero. Therefore we can set the vertical component of the vehicles's normal force equal to its weight:
 Ncosθ =mg" (Wikipedia)

Comment: @YuCarl I've edited my answer. I think I was thinking about a static case, without a turn.

Comment: So the object "slides" horizontally towards the center. Since the curve is turning constantly, the object "appears" to be on the surface?

Comment: @YuCarl In reality, there's no motion to the center. The object is always touching the surface and is always the same distance away from the center.